# "Community wiki" checkbox state lost on failed post

Tags: bug, self-answer, asking-questions, community-wiki

I recently ran into this issue making a post. When answering your own question at the same time you post it, if you check the "community wiki" box but there is a problem with the post on submit (e.g. short title, missing tags), the state of the "community wiki" checkbox is lost and the box is quietly unchecked.

Steps to recreate:

1. [Ask a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)
2. Click "Answer your own question".
3. Check "Community Wiki" for the answer.
4. Make sure something is wrong with the post (e.g. missing tags)
5. Press "Post Your Question".
6. The red notification boxes will pop up and you will remain on the page. However, the "community wiki" checkbox is unchecked.

Expected: All information, including "community wiki" checkbox is preserved.

Actual: All information is preserved *except* the "community wiki" checkbox, which is unchecked.

Comment: +1 I experienced [same issue today](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26741191/1207195), it's still not fixed.